# How can I replace multiple 3 line blocks of text in a file with a single line of text containing the same data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file containing multiple 3 line blocks of text followed by a single new line. My data looks like this:

```
title A - description
http://www.a.site.com/
http://a.anothersite.com/

title B - blah blah
http://www.site.b.com/
http://b.anothersite.com/

title C - yeah yeah
http://www.site.c.com/
http://anothersite.c.com/
```

The output I'm hoping to achieve is something like this:

```
title A - description | http://www.a.site.com/ | http://a.anothersite.com/   
title B - blah blah | http://www.site.b.com/ | http://b.anothersite.com/
title C - yeah yeah | http://www.site.c.com/ | http://anothersite.c.com/
```

I've been trying to do this with python and I'm not really getting anywhere. The best I was able to accomplish was removing all new lines but that doesn't really help in this case as I still need a new line between each piece of data. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
import re
with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    text = " | ".join(f.readlines())
    text = re.sub(r"(?<!^)\n", '', text)
    text = re.sub(r"\s*\|\s*\|\s*", "\n", text)

    f.seek(0)
    f.write(text)
```

**Output of `file.txt`:**

```
title A - description | http://www.a.site.com/ | http://a.anothersite.com/
title B - blah blah | http://www.site.b.com/ | http://b.anothersite.com/
title C - yeah yeah | http://www.site.c.com/ | http://anothersite.c.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
three_lines_joined = ''
strings_to_join = []
results = []


for index, item in enumerate(text):
    if item is not '\n':
        strings_to_join.append(item.strip())
    else:
        three_lines_joined = ' | '.join(strings_to_join)
        results.append(three_lines_joined)
        three_lines_joined = ''
        strings_to_join = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using regular expressions and replace

```
import re

text = """
title A - description
http://www.a.site.com/
http://a.anothersite.com/

title B - blah blah
http://www.site.b.com/
http://b.anothersite.com/

title C - yeah yeah
http://www.site.c.com/
http://anothersite.c.com/
"""

text = text.strip()
text = re.sub('[^\n](\n)[^\n]', ' | ', text).replace('\n\n', '\n')

print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove empty lines as you did, then use `lines = fulltext.split("\n")` to get a list of lines. Then run something like this:

```
for i in range(len(lines))/3:
    title, desc = lines[3*a].split("-")
    website1, website2 = lines[3*a+1], lines[3*a+2]
    print(title + " - " + desc + " | " + website1 + " - " + website2)
```

which allows you to also use the variables in your code. If you really just want a text output then looking at your input try:

```
fulltext.replace("\n"," ")
```

which should produce your desired text output (maybe with a little modification). However, I'd reccomend the first version more as it would allow you to later for example use those values for something else. Variales are generally more useful then formatted text documents.